# comprehending the nature of multivariable equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to determine what equations such as $(x+1)^2+(y-2)^2=0\ $ and $x^2 +(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2=0$ determine in the $\Bbb R^3$ space? I can't tell when it's a plane and when it's a line...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, of course, is to use a 3-dimensional grapher and see. Of course, this can be misleading and inaccurate.

The usual way is to build up knowledge of a variety of kinds of graphs. Your first example is the standard equation for a circle in the plane with center $(-1,2)$ and radius $0$--i.e. the point $(-1,2)$ in the plane. In 3D this would be a line through $(-1,2)$ perpendicular to the $xy$ plane.

Your second example is a sphere centered at $(0,1,-1)$ with radius zero. In other words, just the point $(0,1,-1)$.

A plane is determined by an equation $ax+by+cz=d$ with at least one of $a,b,c$ non-zero, so if you can get the equation into that form it is a plane.

A line is usually a degenerate quadratic form (conic section), such as in your first example. There is no standard single equation for a line: it is usually given parametrically or as the intersection of two planes.

In other words, there is no general method for recognizing a graph in 3D space from its equation. You can build up a toolkit for recognizing the more common ones. If you want to build up such a toolkit, begin with 2D lines and conic sections, then 3D linear equations giving planes, then 3D quadratic forms and their degenerates.

Comment: thanks I'll see what can be done about this.....